# How to implement my own loop in a Handler/Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, handler

After a lot of investigation about Threads and HandlerThreads I cannot find what I need.
I need to send messages from my UI-thread to another thread and I found that HandlerThread may be the solution BUT I need to have MY OWN loop instead of the standard Looper.loop():

```
class Worker extends Thread {
    public Handler handler;
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // ...
            }
        };
        Looper.loop(); <<<<<< how to implement my own "while()" loop ??
    }
}
```

This is because, it needs to have my own "while" loop doing some work and I need to receive (and send) messages from the UI thread all at same time.

Is there another way to implement all of this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a library? Looper is not part of standard Java.

Comment: It's part of the Android api.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a while loop in the UI thread the UI will become unresponsive. That's the entire reason to move such work to other threads.

The Handler/Looper stuff is a way to get access to a properly synchronized message queue
associated to a thread. It's a good way to communicate between threads, Not a mechanism to
do two simultaneous things in one thread.

Now, what you should do instead is a dependent on the problem you are trying to solve. There
are many mechanism for doing background work in android and selecting between them isn't easy
if we have no clue about the problems you are facing.

-edit in response to comment-

I'm not confident in my android threading design skills, so take what I'm about to suggest
with a grain of salt.

My suggestion would be to implement your handler thread. Take the body of the while loop
and implement it as a runnable, most likely as an inner class in your handler or something
similar. The last thing the runnable should do is to post itself to the handler. The
handler should also have the handleMessage method to handle any messages from the UI
thread. The idea here is that the looper for the handler thread will interleave the
runnable and the handling of messages, but because both happens in the same thread
you will not need any extra synchronization. You also need to post the runnable once
from the run method of the handlerThread before you start the looper.

It's also perfectly fine to handle threads in a normal java like fashion in android but
you run into all the usual synchronization problems when you do that, plus a whole bunch
more that pops up because of the activity life cycle stuff you have to deal with.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I think the solution to my problem should be simpler than what I stated before. What I´m trying to do is a secondary thread running my own "infinite" loop into (implemented with a while), doing many things. Now I need to send messages from the main UI-thread to that secondary thread, using Handler may be ?. According as I saw, using HandlerThread could be the solution, BUT in that case I cannot implement my own "infinite" loop, because I have a Lopper.loop() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looper, HandlerThread, and all related classes are based on Java Threading system, and they are all open source. You can get the source and modify it for your need (e.g. you can find Looper code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java) )

But as they said in other answers as well, I don't think if this is a good idea. You should be able to easily do what you need using the current implementation of the Looper and HandlerThread. The requirement you mentioned was not clear to me so I am not still sure why you might want to use a custom Looper.